# Plausibility of plastic bones

Tags: biology, xenobiology, chemistry, anatomy, biochemistry

So, how possible are plastic bones? Take clorox by Stephen L. Gullet for example, organisms use chlorine as a defense mechanism, which eventually accumulated in the atmosphere (1%),which caused plants to be made out of PVC. If I were to take this to a next level and made creatures have plastic bones, what kind of chlorine concentration would I need? Is it even possible? And what plastic would their bones be made out of?

Comment: More plausible than pure metal bones IMO.

Comment: Why would you need free chlorine in the atmosphere to have bones made of PVC?  Simply get the needed chlorine from NaCl.  Also consider that PVC is far from the only kind of plastic out there.  ABS is just carbon, hydrogen, and nitrogen, teflon is carbon & fluorine...  And you really want a composite, not pure plastic.

Answer (score 2):

Real human bones are made of polymers, that's plastic.

Actually most living tissue on this planet is either metallic based or a type of biological plastic

Even the fat under your skin is a polymer, so is your salive and...similar liquids

There's more metal and plastic in your head when compared to the average portable computer.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @EkadhSingh Doh! You're right. My bad. Sorry for the trouble!